# Javafx Stage visibility property

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a java app using primarily JavaFX for the UI. I have been using only `Stage.show()` and `Stage.hide()` up until this point to display the different windows.

I now need a way to get the visibility for a specific window at the stage level. I might be overlooking something but a cant find a `.getVisibility()` method for the Stage class.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the [`isShowing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#isShowing--) property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use the stage.isShowing() to determine if it's visible or not.